# Glitchy behavior in twitter-bootstrap responsive menu

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to get the menu bar of an example on the tb website to be a constant height throughout and I ran into a bit of odd behavior.

In the following demo:

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/examples/fluid.html

If you resize your browser to about 1070/1080 px width, the bar jumps to an ugly height and then back down.  It's as if there's a media query somewhere in the responsive css that hasn't accounted for a ~2px range in browser width.  I'm using this as a baseline for my application and would absolutely appreciate any suggestions on how to get this fixed.

Comment: I'm not seeing it. What browser?

Comment: Finally got it at 994x978 in Firefox.

Comment: The amount of people this would effect would be so small (if any) there is no point wasting your time on it.

Comment: @KyleNeedham - that doesn't mean it's not a bug and can't be asked. In the end, that's what SO is for.

Comment: If anyone went resize-happy on my site I'd want them to be impressed, that's all :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue comes from some page specific style (from fluid.html):

```
@media (max-width: 980px) {
    .navbar-text.pull-right {
        float: none;
        padding-left: 5px;
        padding-right: 5px;
    }
}
```

vs some external CSS (from bootstrap-responsive.css):

```
@media (max-width: 979px) {
    .nav-collapse .nav {
        float: none;
        margin: 0 0 10px;
    }
}
```

As you can see, there is a 1px difference between those media-queries.  If you were to edit the first to also use 979px, things would not jump any more.

Answer (score 0):

There's a spot in there where `.navbar-text.pull-right` goes to `{float: none}` before `.nav-collapse` goes to `{height: 0}`. I'd look for that.

UPDATE: It's in the page styles:

```
  @media (max-width: 980px) {
    /* Enable use of floated navbar text */
    .navbar-text.pull-right {
      float: none;
      padding-left: 5px;
      padding-right: 5px;
    }
  }
```